# Laravel Image Resize Problem (image-intervention)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to resize the input image in laravel controller with image-intervention. Now I'm getting a problem.

Error screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQThq.jpg

My Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu7IW.jpg

Its showing the error like this:

> Quality must range from 0 to 100.

```
if ($request -> hasFile('profile_picture')) {
    $path = time().
    'team.'.$request->profile_picture->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $resize_image = Image::make($request->profile_picture)->resize(300, 300)->encode('jpg');
    $resize_image->save(public_path('images'), $path);
    $team->profile_picture = $path;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `comma` in your code which should be `dot`, so change

```
$resize_image->save(public_path('images'), $path);
```

to

```
$resize_image->save(public_path('images') . $path);
```

Save function first parameter is `path` and second is quality. Quality is optional.

Ref : [Link](http://image.intervention.io/api/save)

Comment: Same error? `$resize_image->save(public_path('images') . $path, 50);` can you try this.

Comment: The Error has gone, but it not storing any image in public/images folder... And for this reason the image can't preview ( https://imgur.com/a/S6AwTHA )... Although it sending value(0x313534373337353231367465616D2E6A7067 ) to the database...

Comment: You are doing this locally or in test server? `public/images` give proper permission to the directory

Comment: Opps...! The images are storing directly into the public folder... How could I Solve this...?

Comment: @NIKHILKURMI can you try `$resize_image->save(url('images') . $path, 50);`

Comment: And make sure there is `images` directory inside public folder

Comment: Now its showing this error message:
"Can't write image data to path (http://veechi.test/images1547376026team.jpg)"

Comment: `$resize_image->save(url('images/') . $path, 50);` try this one or final try `$resize_image->save(url('public/images/') . $path, 50);` :)

Comment: Thanks a Lot...
I was already been trying this $resize_image->save('images/' . $path, 50);
and its working...

Comment: I have a question, if `$resize_image->save('images/' . $path, 50);` this one works properly, then why `$resize_image->save(url('public/images/') . $path, 50);` its not working...? 
@Iftikhar uddin

Comment: URL function starts from '/public' so anything you pass in parameter is appended after public

Comment: You Mean `$resize_image->save(url('images/') . $path, 50);` this will work...?

but unfortunately it also returning same error:  **Now its showing this error message: "Can't write image data to path**

Comment: @NIKHILKURMI sorry for confusion i didn't read the previous comments properly! I think URL and public_path funcs aren't working in save method right? So one thing you can do is save the whole path in $path variable and then pass it to `->save($path, 50);` like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is here :
change this line From :

```
 $resize_image->save(public_path('images'), $path);
```

to

```
 $resize_image->save(public_path('images').$path,100);
```

// 100 is the number of your image quality. This can be only 0 to 100.